# working with Grid View

Tags: android, gridview

I am preparing an application with Grid view with 2 row 2 column . The scenario is

1. When open the screen, it should load default image from the drawable image folder.
2. The first grid has (+) as image and rest of the grid should have default image.
3. User click on (+) image and it opens a list of names. upon selecting a name. it should come back to Grid view and update the first grid with text view.
4. Then my first grid should show textview with the selected name. (Imageview should disapear)
5. paralley the (+) image should move to the second grid ..

This operation I need to acomplish to add names in all the grids. The + image keeps on moving through the grid until all grids have text view

Can someone tell me how to achieve updating images with text view and moving the image view (+ icon) across the grids.

Comment: When ever new image came have to update data in adapter and notify it.

Comment: Please give me some examples as i am not good in UI implementation. Help me to understand how to update the images on the grid cells

Answer (score 0):

After searching in Internet i found how to create a gallery of images using Grid view. 
But after implementing , i cannot see the first grid cell. It is hidden. I can see only 2,3 and 4 cells out of the grid view. 1st cell is only half shown.

my Grid view details are

```
 <GridView
        android:id="@+id/Favorite_GridView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/Date_RelativeLayout"
        android:columnWidth="90dp"            
        android:listSelector="@drawable/gridview_norecode_selector"
        android:numColumns="2"            
        android:gravity="center"            
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

Inside my Adapter code :

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ViewHolder holder = null;
  if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.four_grid, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.imageTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Day_TextView);
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

            Display screen = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
            int width = Math.min(screen.getWidth() / 2, mgridView.getHeight() / 2);
            holder.image.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, width));
            holder.image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
```

Please let me know where i am wrong. Why i the 1st cell of the grid is half hidden.